# error con try cacthen php

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un login para validar al usuario, pero al momento de usar las instrucciones `try` y `catch` de **php**  me arroja un error. He probado muchas maneras pero sigo sin hacerlo funcionar, mi código:

```
    <?php

{
try{
    echo entero('string');
    $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=trabajofinal" , "root", "");
    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios=  WHERE usuarios=:login AND password= :password";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $login=htmlentities(addcslashes($_POST["Login"]));{
    $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));{
    $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
    $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

    $resultado->execute(); //ejecuta la consulta


    $id=$resultado->rowCount(); //devuelve 0 y 1 y lo guarda


    if($id!=0){
        echo "Bienvenido";


        }

    catch(Exception $ex){  //Aqui da error  
        echo('Excepci&oacute;n capturada:'  . $ex->getMessage());

    }
```

Intente de esta manera y también da error

```
?>
  catch(Exception $e){

  die("Error:" . $e->getMessage());


        }
```

El Error:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\compruebalogin.php on line 28

Mi version de php Versión de PHP: **7.2.3**

Comment: Buen día revisa por favor con identación que tus llaves se encuentren correctas y completas, posible repetido de la pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457048/i-keep-on-getting-an-error-syntax-error-unexpected-catch-t-catch

Comment: Te falta cerrar el bracket del try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, revisa porfa tu identación y que las llaves se encuentren completas, como te muestro a continuación:

```
<?php

try{
    echo entero('string');
    $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=trabajofinal" , "root", "");
    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios=  WHERE usuarios=:login AND password= :password";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $login=htmlentities(addcslashes($_POST["Login"]));{
    $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));{
    $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
    $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

    $resultado->execute(); //ejecuta la consulta


    $id=$resultado->rowCount(); //devuelve 0 y 1 y lo guarda


    if($id!=0){
        echo "Bienvenido";


        }

    }catch(Exception $ex){  //Aqui da error  
        echo('Excepci&oacute;n capturada:'  . $ex->getMessage());

    }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.